# Removing duplicates from Angular JS ng-options / ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following:

```
$scope.jsonmarkers = [{
    "name": "Jeff",
        "type": "Organisation + Training Entity",
        "userID": "1"
}, {
    "name": "Fred",
        "type": "Organisation + Training Entity",
        "userID": "2"
}];
```

And this in my html:

```
<select id="typeselect"  multiple  ng-options="accnts.type for accnts in jsonmarkers" ng-model="accnt" ng-change="changeaccnt(accnt.type)"></select>
```

How do I go about matching the type and only echoing it once per appearance in the `ng-options`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For removing duplicates you could use the **unique** filter from AngularUI (source code available here: [AngularUI unique filter](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js)) and use it directly in the ng-options (or ng-repeat).

Look here for more: **[Unique & Stuff](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/)**

Also there's a syntax error in json structure.

**[Working Code](http://jsfiddle.net/YJQx6/5/)**

**Html**

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
        <select id="typeselect"  ng-options="accnts.type for accnts in jsonmarkers | unique:'type'" ng-model="accnt" ng-change="changeaccnt(accnt.type)" multiple></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
    var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("MainController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.jsonmarkers = [{
        "name": "Jeff",
            "type": "Organisation + Training Entity",
            "userID": "1"
    }, {
        "name": "Fred",
            "type": "Organisation + Training Entity",
            "userID": "2"
    }];
});


app.filter('unique', function () {

    return function (items, filterOn) {

        if (filterOn === false) {
            return items;
        }

        if ((filterOn || angular.isUndefined(filterOn)) && angular.isArray(items)) {
            var hashCheck = {}, newItems = [];

            var extractValueToCompare = function (item) {
                if (angular.isObject(item) && angular.isString(filterOn)) {
                    return item[filterOn];
                } else {
                    return item;
                }
            };

            angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
                var valueToCheck, isDuplicate = false;

                for (var i = 0; i < newItems.length; i++) {
                    if (angular.equals(extractValueToCompare(newItems[i]), extractValueToCompare(item))) {
                        isDuplicate = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!isDuplicate) {
                    newItems.push(item);
                }

            });
            items = newItems;
        }
        return items;
    };
});
```

Comment: I need Organisation + Training Entity only once not twice

Comment: Hi @vimes1984 please look at this quesion and I am looking for same answer please update my plunker as well to know the exact solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47453677/how-to-get-unique-drop-down-value-instead-of-multiple-in-angular-js?noredirect=1#comment81862180_47453677 thanks

Answer (score 1):

I modified the answer that NidhishKrishnan gave in order to make the answer work for nested objects.

For example if you have:

```
$scope.jsonmarkers = [{
    "name": "Jeff",
    "type": "Organisation + Training Entity",
    "userID": "1",
    "userData": {
        "hire reason":"training"
    }
}, {
    "name": "Fred",
    "type": "Organisation + Training Entity",
    "userID": "2"
    "userData": {
        "hire reason":"training"
    }
}];
```

This is the modified version:

```
angular.module('ArtifactFeederApp.filters', [])

    .filter('unique', function () {
    return function (items, filterOn) {

        if (filterOn === false) {
            return items;
        }

        if ((filterOn || angular.isUndefined(filterOn)) && angular.isArray(items)) {
            var hashCheck = {}, newItems = [];

            var extractValueToCompare = function (item) {
                if (angular.isObject(item) && angular.isString(filterOn)) {

                    var resolveSearch = function(object, keyString){
                        if(typeof object == 'undefined'){
                            return object;
                        }
                        var values = keyString.split(".");
                        var firstValue = values[0];
                        keyString = keyString.replace(firstValue + ".", "");
                        if(values.length > 1){
                            return resolveSearch(object[firstValue], keyString);
                        } else {
                            return object[firstValue];
                        }
                    }

                    return resolveSearch(item, filterOn);
                } else {
                    return item;
                }
            };

            angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
                var valueToCheck, isDuplicate = false;

                for (var i = 0; i < newItems.length; i++) {
                    if (angular.equals(extractValueToCompare(newItems[i]), extractValueToCompare(item))) {
                        isDuplicate = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!isDuplicate) {
                    if(typeof item != 'undefined'){
                        newItems.push(item);
                    }
                }

            });
            items = newItems;
        }
        return items;
    };
});
```

You can now do:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <select id="typeselect"  ng-options="accnts.type for accnts in jsonmarkers | unique:'userData.hire reason'" ng-model="accnt" ng-change="changeaccnt(accnt.type)" multiple></select>
</div>
```

And you will see a list that only shows training as an option.